# sql unique mapping of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database where there are n products ,m units sold on different dates. 
Like bags are sold on daily basis , some days 5 some days 6 etc.

Sample database :

```
+---------+----------+-------+
| Product | UnitSold | Date  |
+---------+----------+-------+
| bag     |        1 | 1 jun |
| wallet  |        2 | 2 jun |
| purse   |        3 | 3 jun |
| bag     |        4 | 4 jun |
| shoes   |        3 | 4 jun |
| Shirt   |        2 | 1 jun |
| bag     |        5 | 2 jun |
| shirt   |        6 | 3 jun |
| Purse   |        1 | 1 jun |
+---------+----------+-------+
```

I want a unique combination of results where a particular quantity of a product is sold on particular date. How can I do that?
Example I am looking for :

Result:

```
+---------+----------+-------+
| Product | UnitSold | Date  |
+---------+----------+-------+
| bag     |        1 | 1 jun |
| purse   |        3 | 3 jun |
| shirt   |        6 | 3 jun |
+---------+----------+-------+
```

Want a specific mapping of columns
How can I do that ? I am using Microsoft sql server 2008

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results -- in a tabular format.

Comment: I have edited . Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

You could throw in a rank or row number if you don't care about what result you really want.

I threw your data into a temp table and ran the following. It will give me one result per product. With rank, it will give me number 1 based on unit sold. You can change that if you want, based on date or whatever else.

```
select *
from (
select *,rank() over(partition by product order by unitsold ) as rnk
from #temp a 
)final
where rnk = 1

product unitsold    Date    rnk
bag     1        2017-06-01  1
purse   3        2017-06-02  1
shirt   2        2017-06-02  1
shoes   3        2017-06-04  1
wallet  2        2017-06-02  1
```